# Wrapping a method using several source files

Tags: raku

I'm trying to understand how wrapping works in perl6. I'm using this code:

First file (test.pl6):

```
use v6;
use lib '.';

use TestClass;

my TestClass $t .= new;
$t.wrapped(1, 7);
```

Second file (TestClass.pm6):

```
multi sub trait_mod:<is>(Routine:D \r, :$dummy!)
{
    r.wrap(sub (|)
    {
        say 'Dummy';
        callsame;
    });
}

unit class TestClass;

method wrapped($a, $b) is dummy
{
    say "Wrapped ($a, $b)";
}
```

When executing **test.pl6**, I get:

```
Cannot invoke this object (REPR: Null; VMNull)
  in sub  at TestClass.pm6 (TestClass) line 5
  in any enter at gen/moar/Metamodel.nqp line 3999
  in block <unit> at test.pl6 line 7
```

When all the code above is in the same file, it works and prints **Dummy** first and then **Wrapped (1, 7)**.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a bug according to RT issue [#129096](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=129096#ticket-history): "[BUG] sub wrapped with mod_trait: when exported yield cryptic error message, works fine in same unit". In a comment dated 26 Aug 2016, this bug lists a bunch of other bugs that the reporter thinks are related because they represent an "outer context lost with compile time closure" bug.

Among the list of related bugs is one that has [a comment dated 10 April 2016](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=127860#txn-1395331) that says:

> I'm actually surprised there are as few "Cannot invoke this object"
>   tickets:
>
> [(RT search for that message)](https://rt.perl.org/Search/Simple.html?q=%22Cannot+invoke+this+object%22)
>
> A cursory survey of those would suggest that they all fall in a wider
>   category of "code attribute of some type not surviving precompilation"

I haven't reviewed all the apparently related bugs or asked on #perl6-dev about what devs think about them.